# How does rails converts post variables types?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

On the view I have this

```
<%= hidden_field :hold, i, value: true %>
```

on the controller I realize that both :hold and value are strings.

```
params[:hold]['0'] == 'true'  =>  true
params[:hold][0] => nil
```

Is there a best practice on type converting between the view and the controller ?

Comment: A suggestion: If your `i` variable is an integer index and you're creating those hidden fields in a loop,  then maybe it might be more clear and easier to work with if you appended the index to a word; for example: `<%= hidden_field :hold, "index#{i}".to_sym, value: true%>`. Then in your controller, you can simply get the value using `:index1`. If that's any easier...otherwise the answer below is correct as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I am getting it right. But, params is like a hash. And everything you get from params are strings. So params should look like this:

```
params = {'hold': {'0': 'true'}}
```

You can get 'true' via strings, like this:

```
params['hold']['0']
```

Or you can do it with symbols, like this:

```
params[:hold][:'0']
```

Since :0 is not syntactically correct, you must use :'0' to create a symbol.

It really depends on personal preference as to which to use. I would do it like:

```
params[:hold]['0']
```